# Using SQL Developer, I want to display only the numbers from a string after a specific character

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer (and it must be with SQL Developer), I need to take a string that looks like XML data but it really is just a string and display the data into a table.  The data is from a large table that has no numbers in some user Id's and some that has no numbers in Job Ids but the XML like tags are still there.  Again, it is not XML just made to look like XML so no XML commands will work.

Data:

```
<UserId>1234567</UserId><JobId>1234567890123</JobId><Date>Wed May 09 13:08:24 EDT 2018</Date>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
select company_id, location_id, 
    regexp_substr(xml_provision_responses,'UserId>([[:digit:]]+<?)') as USER_Id,
    regexp_substr(xml_provision_responses,'UserPitId>([[:digit:]]+<?)') as JOB_ID
From Entitymgr.Cr_Response_Matrix
Where CAST(regexp_replace(SUBSTR(xml_provision_responses,-24,4), '[^0-9]','')as varchar(20))='2018' 
    and company_Id = 9876543 and location_Id = 9876543210987;
```

The first Where condition was just to limit the data pull to just this year and the second Where condition was just added to just focus on one data point so that part does not matter.

Expected output:

COMPANY_ID: 9876543

LOCATION_Id: 9876543210987

USER_ID: 1234567

JOB_ID: 1234567890123

========================================

Actual Output:

COMPANY_ID: 9876543

LOCATION_Id: 9876543210987

USER_ID: UserId>1234567<

JOB_ID: JobId>1234567890123<

========================================

I want to only display the number portion of the string that are between the > < tags.  And if there is no number between the tags to put null or the word missing into the table in that specific column.

Comment: Honestly you might be better off doing some pre-processing of your XML content outside Oracle using a proper parser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some more parameters of [`regexp_substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099):

```
select regexp_substr(xml_provision_responses, '(<JobId>)(.*)(</JobId>)', 1, 1, 'i', 2),
       regexp_substr(xml_provision_responses, '(<UserId>)(.*)(</UserId>)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
...
```

The idea is to divide the matching string into 3 parts:

- the tag opening (`(<UserId>)`)
- the content (`(.*)`)
- the tag closure (`(</UserId>)`)

and then only get the second matching subexpression (see the parameter `2` in the function calls.

Comment: Thank you.  This is now doing exactly what I wanted it to.  I have been trying to use regexp_substr without fully understanding it and have spent way too much time on this.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that you said (and stressed) that the string is not XML, but what you've shown does seem to be enough like XML to let you use the XML functions in the database anyway:

```
-- cte for your data
with cr_response_matrix (company_id, location_id, xml_provision_responses) as (
  select 9876543, 9876543210987,
    '<UserId>1234567</UserId><JobId>1234567890123</JobId><Date>Wed May 09 13:08:24 EDT 2018</Date>'
  from dual
)
-- actual query
select crm.company_id, crm.location_id, xml.user_id, xml.job_id
from cr_response_matrix crm
cross join xmltable ('/root'
  passing xmltype('<root>' || xml_provision_responses || '</root>')
  columns user_id number path 'UserId',
    job_id number path 'JobId',
    tsz_str varchar2(28) path 'Date'
) xml
where substr(tsz_str, -4) = '2018';

     COMPANY_ID     LOCATION_ID         USER_ID          JOB_ID
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
        9876543   9876543210987         1234567   1234567890123
```

Of course, your actual strings might have other stuff that makes this approach invalid.

---

You could add an XML header as well as a dummy root node:

```
select crm.company_id, crm.location_id, xml.user_id, xml.job_id
from cr_response_matrix crm
cross join xmltable ('/root'
  passing xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><root>'
    || xml_provision_responses || '</root>')
  columns user_id number path 'UserId',
    job_id number path 'JobId',
    tsz_str varchar2(28) path 'Date'
) xml
where extract(year from to_timestamp_tz(replace(xml.tsz_str, ' E', ' US/Eastern E'),
  'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZR TZD YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')) = 2018;
```

Just for fun I've also converted the `Date` value to a full timestamp with time zone to extract the actual year instead of using `substr()`.

But this is all academic if the data isn't consistently as close to XML as your example suggested, and the adjusted regular expressions are reliable.

Can't say you didn't warn me...

Comment: I went with XML commands to start with because, as you said, it looks a lot like an XML data line.  Every time I would try to though, I got an error message stating something along the lines of missing xml header or something like that.  Apparently, whoever built this table, this specific column that the data exists in was pull from xml data from somewhere else and built in as a string.  Not sure where the original xml data come from and I doubt that I would have access to it so I had to work with this XML like string instead.

Comment: Well, I'm just adding a dummy root node, but you could add an XML header at the same time. It sounds like the actual values are rather more varied than your example suggests though? It's academic if the regex route works reliably though.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  This is the first time I am actually working with XML data in real world applications so I am not that good with it.  Thanks for input though.  It may help me out down the line.